# Promise all making four api calls instead of two api calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, promise, angular-promise

I making two api call using `Promise.all` and `toPromise()` as below:

```
Promise.all(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map((hostName) => {
    return this.serviceC.status(hostName)
        .then(res => {
            const oretry: ORInterface = {
                oQid: res.rows[0].qid,
                reason: this.reason
            };
            return this.serviceB.retry(oretry).toPromise();
        })
        .then(() => {
            return Promise.all(this.Id.slice(0, this.Id.length).map(id => {
                const sretry: SDInterface = {
                    hostName,
                    Id: id,
                    reason: this.reason
                };

                this.serviceB.createDbEntry(sentry).toPromise();
                }));
            });
    }))
    .then(() => {
        this.dialog.close();
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

Here `this.serviceB.retry(oretry)` is being executed correctly.
But, `this.serviceB.createDbEntry(sentry)` is being executed twice.

The `hostName array` has two values: `hostA` and `hostB`

Similarly, the `Id array` has two values: `Id1` and `Id2`

Now, the issue is that `this.serviceB.createDbEntry(sentry)` is creating four db entries as below:

```
`hostA` `Id1`
`hostA` `Id2`
`hostB` `Id1`
`hostB` `Id2`
```

It should only make two entries:

```
`hostA` `Id1`
`hostB` `Id2`
```

Comment: what is behind this.serviceB.createDbEntry(sentry), what is the implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your hostname and id seem related, you should not do a `map` over the whole `this.id` slice, but just take the one that corresponds to the current hostname.

So, get the sequential index of the current hostname as follows:

```
Promise.all(this.hostName.slice(0, this.Id.length).map((hostName, i) => {
//                                                              ^^^^
```

And then further down, don't do another, nested  `Promise.all`, but:

```
.then(() => {
    let id = this.Id[i];
    const sretry: SDInterface = {
        hostName,
        Id: id,
        reason: this.reason
    };
    return this.serviceB.createDbEntry(sretry).toPromise();
});
```

Also, fix the spelling of `sretry` in that last line (you have `sentry`)